# Need regex for mobile number start with 61 to 99 with 10 digit number

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

Requirement is mobile number should start with 61 to 99
like 61xxxxxxxx, 62xxxxxxxxx... , 99xxxxxxxxxx

Need regular expression to match this case. 
If mobile no is start with 0 or 11,12 or anything less than 61 then it should be invalid

Mobile no is max 10 digits, no country code needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better off using whatever programming tool you have to evaluate whether the first 2 digits are in range, far simpler and probably performant too. However, if you strictly want to use regex, this will do-
`(?:6[1-9]|[7-9][0-9])\d{8}$`

Here's the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/skOIjd/2)

It essentially, checks the first digit, if it's a 6, the next digit should be in range [1-9], if it's a 7, 8 or 9 (i.e range [7-9]), the next digit can be in range [0-9]. Then there should be 8 digits that follow.

Ofcourse, this above is a simple and easy to understand solution. Essentially checking each first digit and then matching the next. However if your regex flavor supports negative lookbehind, you could probably shorten this *a bit more* (sacrificing readability for brevity) but I do prefer this.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the prefix for the numbers and add a pattern for the remaining 8 digits.

Something like this

```
const regexp = new RegExp('('+[...Array(39).keys()].map(key => key + 61).join('|') + ')\\d{8,8}')
```